# Android button animation flickering

Tags: android, animation, button

I have already able to animate a button, but upon further enquiry I have to explicitly set the position of button so that the animation looks completed.

When I try to do that, I check the button animation listener and then when animation finish I set drawable res to drawable I want. But the previous drawable is visible and then the set drawable gets visible hence the flicker.

I have tried using null and then mounting the new image but its not working out.

So how can I proceed further?

Comment: Any body, please can you solve this question?

Comment: Hey guys, please help!!